# Nodejs how can I add another main app.js and use both of them to make my code clean?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, authentication

Hello I'm using nodejs and express framework and I wrote all my serverside code into my app.js file but it's little bit complicated for me cause cause I have almost 250 line code and I want to implement authentication now so I want to create another app.js to write my code only for auth so other code will not confuse me how can I do that????

**UPDATED**
[image]

as you se above I have 2 post requests from my app.js I asking that how I will get thoso request in my auth.js file cause as I understand exports  import for static js field I want to take request and save that information my database and I want to that in my auth.js file

Comment: Divide you code into 2 separate files. The first (app.js) is the main/entry point of you application that can be "launched" using *node app.js*. The second (for example auth.js) is where all your authentication system goes. Rememebr that structuring your application is a must and can be hard at first but as your app size increase the more helpful it gets. You can see my "structure" at [this](https://github.com/carlocorradini/racer-server) repository.

Comment: Remember, having long and complicated files is not good. Sometimes it's better to stop and make a refactoring of the code.

Comment: thank you I will listen your advice :)

Comment: See [this](https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-module-exports-exports-node-js/) guide on nodeJs modules

Comment: thank you for your information but it's not what exactly I want can you check updates

Comment: You can see my boilerplate which i recently uploaded as Github repo:
https://github.com/cybercoder/babelnodeboilerplate
Also there's another boilerplates too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a simplified structure for your project derived from my project at [this](https://github.com/carlocorradini/racer-server) link.

**routes.js**:

*Create a file named route.js where you define all the routes for your application. In this case the routes will be only the register and the login routes that will be handled by the UserController module.*

```js
import { Router } from 'express';
import UserController from './UserController';

const router = Router();

router.post(
  '/register',
  UserController.register
);
router.post(
  '/login',
  UserController.login
);

export default router;
```

**UserController.js**:

*This file/class that handle all the operations for the creation and login of an user*

**As you can see all the methods has no route url because they are called directly from our route.js file. We are dividing and structuring your application!**

```js
export default class UserController {
  public static register(req, res) {
    // Register operation
  }

  public static login(req, res) {
    // Login operation
  }
}
```

**app.js**

*The entry point and where you are configuring your express application.*

```js
import express from 'express';
import routes from './routes';

const app = express();

// configure app ...

// Here we attach our routes url to the express app
app.use('/', routes)
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

depending on your setup you can divide your files in per example:

- app.js
- authentication.js

and then either require or import functions from the authentication.js file into app.js like this:

```js
import express from "express";
```

or this:

```js
const express = require("express");
```

functions inside the authentication file should be exported like this:

```js
//needs to be imported as this: import {authenticate} from "authenticate";
export function authenticate(){}; 

//needs to be imported as this: import authenticate from "authenticate";
function authenticate(){};
export default authenticate;
```

or this:

```js
// needs to be imported as this: const authenticate = require("authenticate");
module.exports = function authenticate(){};
```

See this [guide](https://timonweb.com/tutorials/how-to-enable-ecmascript-6-imports-in-nodejs/) on enabling ES6 imports as shown above. this has the preference for it can save on memory when importing.

Comment: thank you for your information but it's not what exactly I want can you check updates

Comment: @BarışBabahan Sorry your question was quite unclear, but maybe this example could help: https://github.com/gothinkster/node-express-realworld-example-app/blob/master/app.js in this example they use the router functionality of express to split their code.